# How to add rollback transitions events to Checkout Flow in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

When the user is in the checkout, and he uses the back and forward button to go ahead and go back, the order is no reflecting the state in which screen the user is.

Step to reproduce:

1. List item
2. Add a product to the cart
3. Go to /cart -> the order is in cart state
4. Go to /address using the html button -> The order is in address state
5. Go back to cart using back browser button

The order should be in cart state, but is in address

Whats is the best way to fix that?

Now i added the specific transitions to checkout states in a decorator and added a `before_action` in the Frontend CheckoutControler but i don't know if is the best solution for the issue.

```rb
Spree::Order.class_eval do
state_machine.event :cart do
    transition [:address, :delivery, :payment] => :cart
  end
  state_machine.event :address do
    transition [:delivery, :payment, :cart] => :address
  end
  state_machine.event :delivery do
    transition [:payment, :address] => :delivery
  end
  def change_state_to(state)
    send("#{state}!") if send("can_#{state}?")
  end
end
```

```rb
module Spree
  OrdersController.class_eval do
    def edit
      @order = current_order || Order.incomplete
                                     .includes(line_items: [variant: [:images, :option_values, :product]])
                                     .find_or_initialize_by(guest_token: cookies.signed[:guest_token])
      @order.change_state_to('cart') unless @order.cart?
      associate_user
    end
end
```

```rb
module Spree
  CheckoutController.class_eval do
    after_action :update_order_state, only: [:edit]
    private
    def update_order_state
      return if @order.reload.state == params[:state] || @order.complete?
      @order.change_state_to(params[:state])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is force the page to reload every time you move forward or backward with the browser

```rb
module Spree
  CheckoutController.class_eval do
    before_action :set_cache_headers 

    def set_cache_headers
      response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
      response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
      response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
    end
  end
end
```

Source: https://jacopretorius.net/2014/01/force-page-to-reload-on-browser-back-in-rails.html